# exec com \n não funciona

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando usar a função `exec` em um código que possui `\n`, mas parece que essa função não suporta `\n`

```
a = '''
open('test.txt', 'a').write('Hello, world\n')
'''
exec(a)
```

Erro:

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso funcionar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim - é que quando o compilador Python lê a string que vai dentro da vairável `a`, ele já interpreta o `\n` para ser uma mudança de linha - então o código que o exec vai compilar nesse trecho:

```
a = '''
open('test.txt', 'a').write('Hello, world\n')
'''
exec(a)
```

é enxergado assim:

```
open('test.txt', 'a').write('Hello, world
')
```

O que é um erro de sintaxe.

Você resolve facilmente escapando a `\` com uma barra extra, ou usando uma string raw:

```
a = r'''
open('test.txt', 'a').write('Hello, world\n')
'''
exec(a)
```

(note o "r" prefixando as aspas triplas, na linha do `a =`) - isso faz com que as
"\" em a sejam passadas literalemente para a string, e quando o compilador for interpretar o trecho `write('Hello, world\n')` lá dentro, o \n vai ser expandido, mas dessa vez no lugar certo.

Comment: existe alguma maneira de formatar esse tipo de string?

Answer (score -1):

Você está tentando usar `exec` especificamente?  Ou poderia voce escreve au o documento diretamente?

Como isto: `open('test.txt', 'a').write('Hello, world\n')`

Qualquer jeito, sem comentários `'''`. Isto e por que voce recebe o erro

Editada para o seu comentário:

```
a = open('test.txt', 'a').write('Hello, world\n')
exec(str(a))
```

Comment: Sim, precisava usar o exec

Comment: não faz sentido executar uma expressão e tentar usar o exec no resultado da expressão transformado em string.  
No caso de coisas com efeito colateral, como esse código, se funcionasse (e só depende da representação do objeto que foi o resultado da expressão), ainda corre o risco do efeito acontecer duas vezes.